# Return result from mysql::prepare

Tags: php, mysqli, prepare

Hi this  may sound noob but i have recently started working mysqli->prepare()
i have a following code  and i want to return back the data from my model function to controller   so that i can loop through the data how can i do that?

```
function get_student(){
 $sql = "select student_id from student";
    $stmt = $this->db_con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($student_id);
    return ?
   }

  $result = $model->get_student();
```

PS : I don't want to store my result in an array and than return  i know how to do that

Comment: `return $stmt->fetchall();`

Comment: using fetch_all or fetchall  gives this error Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchall()

Answer (score -1):

`return $stmt->get_result();`

Comment: hi this works but how do I loop through the returned result in my controller?? '